# introduction to real analysis exercise

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that $A$ is bounded if and only if there exists $k > 0$ such that $|x| \le k$ for all $x \in A$. (A set is said to be bounded if it is both bounded above and bounded below).

I assumed that $z \le x \le y$ and from here I can choose such $m$ and $n$ that $z-m=-(y+n)$ and it is done. but I am in doubt how can be sure such $m$ and $n$ exists.

Comment: you need $m$ and $n$ to be special? Take one of them $0$ and solve for the other one.

Comment: Are $z$ and $y$ variables? Use the definitions of bounded above and below to show the existence of constants $M$ and $N$ on either side, then choose $k$ carefully according to which is closer. The other direction should be a one-liner.

Comment: z and y come from definition to be bounded. but the condition "if and only if "  confuses me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(\implies) A $ is given to be bounded. Hence, by definition, there exist $M$ and $N$ such that $A$ is bounded above by $M$ and below by $N$. That is, 
For every $x\in A, N\le x\le M$, choose $k=max (|M|, |N|) $ and show that $|x|\le k$.

Conversely, choose $M=k, N=-k$ and you are done.

Comment: thanks Sir I got it

Comment: @emilagazade: You're welcome.